# type 'Any?' has no subscript members (using Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift3

Every time I run this line of code it doesn't work, anyone who can give me a hand in what I can do too change it? Thanks for any help. :)

Below is the error I keep getting

> Type Any? has no subscript members

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var refHandle: UInt!


var postData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    refHandle = ref?.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with:
    { (snapshot) in

        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        print(dataDict)


    })

    let username: String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!

    ref?.child("Users").child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
    { (snapshot) in
        let username = snapshot.value!["Username"] as! String

        self.usernameField.text = username


    })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues.

**1. Optionals**

This is Swift's way of making a variable be in one of two states namely, have a value or be `nil`. A variable can only be in one of these states. You make a variable an optional by adding a question mark in front of it.

**2. Any**

By declaring a variable to be of type `Any`, this means you're not explicitly stating its type during declaration. Firebase makes all of its returns be of type `Any` in order to give us developers the option of fiddling with the data as we so please hence less constraints on our side.

`snapshot.value` is of type `Any` but Firebase always returns a JSON tree and JSON trees can be represented as [Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html). So what should we do?

1. Since `snapshot.value` is an optional, we should check first to see if its `nil`.
2. If not `nil`, convert it to a dictionary then start accessing the respective elements inside it.

The code below does the job for you and I've added comments to explain what's happening.

```
ref?.child("Users").child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
{ (snapshot) in

    // This does two things.
    // It first checks to see if snapshot.value is nil. If it is nil, then it goes inside the else statement then prints out the statement and stops execution.
    // If it isn't nil though, it converts it into a dictionary that maps a String as its key and the value of type AnyObject then stores this dictionary into the variable firebaseResponse.

    // I used [String:Any] because this will handle all types of data types. So your data can be Int, String, Double and even Arrays.
    guard let firebaseResponse = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else
    {
        print("Snapshot is nil hence no data returned")
        return
    }

    // At this point we just convert the respective element back to its proper data type i.e from AnyObject to say String or Int etc

    let userName = firebaseResponse["Username"] as! String

    self.usernameField.text = username     
})
```

Comment: Swift 3 native Dictionary value type is Any so cast `snapshot.value as? [String:Any]`