# Pull random key/values from FirebaseDatabase in iOS/Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, firebase, swift3

I've created a simple data structure in Firebase:

```
{
  "authors": {
    "John Lennon": [
      "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans.",
      "Time you enjoy wasting, was not wasted."
    ],
    "Steve Jobs": [
      "Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works.",
      "Stay hungry, stay foolish."
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to randomly pick an Author, then choose a random quote from that author. I only have this code so far, which just returns all quotes from the user I manually specified.

```
func loadQuoteFromDatabase()  {

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("authors/John Lennon/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot.value ?? "")

    }) { (error) in
        print (error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The return looks like this:

```
(
    "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans.",
    "Time you enjoy wasting, was not wasted."
)
```

I'm not sure how to get an item out of the parentheses.

I'm an amateur at this sort of coding, so I haven't found this easy to solve. Any ideas how I can grab a random author, then a random quote of theirs?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41836754/4962554) solution useful. Your solution can be found at the `guard let` portion. You need to convert your result into a dictionary.

Comment: @EmilDavid thanks. After using the NSDictionary, I still get similar results. I'm using ` ref?.child("authors").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let result = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            print(result?["John Lennon"] ?? "")
        })` So I'll just have to look at it some more.

Comment: From your JSON structure, *John Lennon* and *Steve Jobs* map to an array. Confirm this by printing out the data type of the result; `print(type(of: result["John Lennon"]))`

Comment: @EmilDavid it actually returns `Optional<Any>` using `print(type(of: result?["John Lennon"]))`

Comment: Firebase returns all of its data back to you as type `Any`. This way you can convert it to whatever type you so please. When sending the data over to your database, you set it to be of a certain type. When retrieving it, you need to cast it back to the format you originally sent it as. For your case, you need to cast `result["John Lennon"]` to whatever format you originally sent it as