# Fetch data from firebase using childAdded in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve some data using the observe(.childAdded) in order to get the new "posts" of my project and add it to the tableview correctly. 
I actually got the result I need using this function.

```
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapShot) in

        let post = snapShot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = post {

            self.postData.insert(actualPost, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    })
```

But it only works for a child that has a value on it like this in FireBase:

```
*Root
  *Posts
     *ChildByAutoId: "post text value"
```

Actually what I'd like  to have is a child with attributes like this:

```
*Root
  *Posts
    *ChildByAutoId 
       -Text: "post text value"
       -UserId: "userId"
       -CreationDate: "date"
       -PostId: "PostId"
       -Likes: Int
       -Author: "name"
```

I'd like to have the same result as using .observe(.childAdded) but I'm unable to do it.
The only way I found that its currently working is this:

```
    func recuperarData(){
    let ref = self.ref

    ref?.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in
        if let posts = snapShot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
            for (_, value) in posts{
                let post = Posts()

                if let autor = value["Author"] as? String ,let likes = value["Likes"] as? Int, let fecha = value["CreationDate"] as? String, let postId = value["PostID"] as? String, let texto = value["Text"] as? String, let userID = value["UserId"] as? String {
                    post.autor = autor
                    post.likes = likes
                    post.fecha = fecha
                    post.PostId = postId
                    post.texto = texto
                    post.UserId = userID
                    self.posts.append(post)                        
                }                    
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }            
    })        
    ref?.removeAllObservers()
}
```

But this only retrieve all the data Once each time I "reload" the tableview and does not add the posts correctly in the order I want.

Does someone knows a correct way to fetch this data using .observe(.childAdded) so I can upgrade the tableview automatically.

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and swift 3
Thanks

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks @NitinGohel but i cant find the correct way, i already rode the Firebase Documentation but its still hard for me.

Comment: When you say you are unable to use observe(.childAdded), can you elaborate on what happens when you try to use it? Because from what I see right now, it's unclear why you can't just use .childAdded and create a dictionary from the snapshot. A little more information would help me know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am shocked no one was able to call out the issue in your original `.childAdded` function.

`let post = snapShot.value as? String` is the problem.

Firebase Database is a key-value pairing so you can't just cast the whole result into a String. You fixed this problem by casting it into a dictionary when doing `.value`. Do the same thing in the `.childAdded` function.

I had a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836754/4962554) explaining dictionary handling in Firebase.